# Is there a way to cancel onCompletionListener?

Tags: android

I'm writing an app with an autoplay feature, basically like a story book.  I set a media player `onCompletionListener` for each activity (page) so that when the narration is done, it starts the next activity (page).  There's an option to turn autoplay off (so you can read it at your own pace)...but turning it off results in the activity --the current page-- "remembering" the previous `onCompletionListener` call (as the back button is used to navigate back to the previous activity).  The ensuing activities (pages) work fine...as the logic check that starts the `onCompletionListener` keeps it from being executed.

I've also tried moving that logic check to `onStart()` [instead of `onCreate`] as the menu where autoplay is toggled takes over the full screen and causes the previous activity (page) to execute `onStop()`.  While this setup keeps the `onCompletionListener` from being executed again...it still doesn't "cancel" the previous `onCompletionListener`.  Note: This is only an issue when an activity (page) has been started with the `autoplay=on`.

I have also briefly tried `super.recreate()` for that particular activity in an attempt to "restart" everything (hopefully, including the `onCompletionListener`).  However, the result was not pretty (activity blanked out and never reinitialized).

I didn't include any code as (to me) this is more of a procedural question.  1. can a `onCompletionListener` be "canceled".  If so, how?  2. If not, (since I'm relatively new to java/android) is the recreate method acceptable/beneficial to "reset" the entire activity (and the `onCompletionListener` inside it)?

I'm targeting API 11 and above.  Any thoughts/constructive criticism would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to cancel a previous setted `onCompletionListener`, you can simply set a new one that does nothing.

Comment: So there is just one oCL for each activity?  I haven't found thorough documentation for this one yet...so I don't fully understand the "lifecycle" of the oCL, if you will.  Is the oCL "killed" after onDestroy for a particular activity?  Or can it still be lingering in the background?

Comment: 1. yes, there is only one listener. if you set a new one it overrides the pervious. 2. if a listener listens to a dead object it will never be called :)

Comment: Great!  Thanks for the clarification...and for you patience with my questions.  I'm trying not to "assume" anything at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Well the way to "cancel" it is use the release method. And you should consider doing that when you open a new page(activity)

Comment: OK...I assume that you are talking about releasing the media player.  I reset the media player for each page to reload the appropriate file for that page...but I don't actually kill it.  I thought that would be a more efficient method and less prone to memory leaks?

Comment: Yes I am. If you don't release the media player the memory used would be the sum total of all the media players and probably could crash the phone. I think it's more efficient to load page by page and release it when activity is ended

Comment: The media player docs state that `reset()` takes it back to its uninitialized state. I assumed that freed up all of the resources used for that particular media player...which looks to be bad assumption.  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You're welcome! You may also want to go through this image http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png and corresponding page http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Answer (score 0):

here're a few possible solutions:

1. for the onDestroy , use setOnCompletionListener(null).
2. upon the required settings change , also set a global flag (that will also be set upon application being created) , and in the listener event , check the flag .

Comment: Thanks. 1. is similar to what Rotem suggested...I will give that a try. I am doing 2.  I just didn't think of the `null` as the target for the oCL.  I will give it a try.